# How do I apply a SumIf Formula in a VBA Sub? Getting Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a Sub that places a `SUMIF` formula in a cell. I have reduced the problem to a simple setup:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Cells(2, 3).Formula = "=SUMIF(A1:A5;D1;B1:B5)"
End Sub
```

[image: Picture of the spreadsheet [http://i.imgur.com/qVSoDkvm.png]]

I get a `1004 Error`.

I can run the same code but with the SUM function instead:

```
"=SUM(B1:B5)"
```

This does not produce an error. Thus I suspect the semicolons in my formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.Formula` accepts formulas in English.
Parameter separator in English is `,`.

If you want to use formulas in the language of your Excel installation, use `.FormulaLocal`.

However to ensure your code will run on any Excel, fix your formula to be in accordance with the `en-us` locale.

Comment: Thank you, it had never occurred to me that the .Formula only accepts English formulas.

Comment: ++ sorry should have found this and marked the other thread as a duplicate :P