# What is wrong with my IF function in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I would like some feedback on the following formula for the specified range, this code seems to work on my laptop but not my desktop for an unknown reason.

[image]

68 & below = "Within Alert Level"

Inclusively between 69 and 98 = "Exceeded Alert Level"

99 & Above = "Exceeded Suspension Level"

```
=IF(A1>=99; "Exceeded Suspension Level"; IF(A1>=69; "Exceeded Alert Level"; IF(A1<=68; "Within Alert Level")))
```

Comment: You should replace the semicolons with commas.  Perhaps the commas somehow got replaced with semicolon when you copied from your laptop to your desktop.

Comment: Do Excels on your two computers have the same locale/international settings? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33540940/11683

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `;` should be `,`

Comment: My laptop doesn't accept "," is showing an error message stating to use insert function from formula tab or click Help. Earlier today, I tried replacing the semicolons with commas too, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Replace ; with , and your formula will work fine

=IF(A1>=99, "Exceeded Suspension Level", IF(A1>=69, "Exceeded Alert Level", IF(A1<=68, "Within Alert Level")))