# Error 1004 FormulaLocal with SEERRO

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use vba to insert a formula into cell on my Sheet. I believe it can be done with the formula I have below, but unfortunately I do not know how to fix my syntax below.

What's wrong with my FormulaLocal syntax?

The strange thing is that using R.Formula, it works, but the cell gets the error #NAME

```
   Sub InsertIFERROR()
        Dim R As Range
        Set R = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
        R.Select
        For Each R In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

            R.FormulaLocal = "=SEERRO(" & Mid(R.FormulaLocal, 2) & ",""-"")"

        Next R
    End Sub
```

Comment: If the error you see is indeed `#NAME`, your Excel might not be in Portuguese at which point you can't specify Portuguese function names in `FormulaLocal`. Why do you want to [use `FormulaLocal`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33540940/11683) anyway?

Comment: `debug.print Mid(R.FormulaLocal, 2)` and see if it returns what you think it should

Comment: Once you solve the "language" issue you can avoid both the `Select` and the loop and simply write `R.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid(R.FormulaLocal, 2) & ",""-"")"`

Comment: But my Excel is in PT-BR. This is the strangest thing. All of my formulas in the Worksheet are in PT-BR. Error #NAME occurs when I use R.Formula, but if I access the cell formula and give an enter, the error disappears

Comment: Doesn't PT-BR use `;` instead of `,` ? Check the original formula or your system's regional setting for the list separator.

Comment: @G.Sena That happens when you provide a local formula using `Formula`. user3598756 [meant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583139/error-1004-formulalocal/42583295?noredirect=1#comment72299637_42583139) `R.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid(R.Formula, 2) & ",""-"")"`, but that will only work if all formulas in `R` are the same, otherwise you do need the loop with that logic inside.

Comment: Perhaps you actually have PT-PT, not PT-BR. In that case, use `SE.ERRO` and a `;` instead of `SEERRO` and `,`.

Comment: @Jeeped That was it..Thanks ever so much.

Comment: Thank you everybody

Comment: I thought that this could reasonably be closed as a typographical error that could not be reproduced then decided instead that the error may be more common than is immediately apparent. I've posted an answer below and edited the question so that the title reflects the problem.

Comment: @Jeeped I have similar doubts about whether or not I should close this as [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33540794/11683).

Comment: @GSerg - Yes, I think on the balance of all things considered, this may be worth keeping for others to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be especially careful about the regional version of your Excel. The PT-PT version uses [SE.ERRO](https://support.office.com/pt-pt/article/SE-ERRO-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-SE-ERRO-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) with a semicolon as a list separator while the PT-BR version uses [SEERRO](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/SEERRO-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-SEERRO-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) (and typically a comma as a list separator).

Answer (score -1):

Try this....Hope it will work and make sense where you done mistake.

```
Sub InsertIFERROR()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
    'R.Select
    For Each rCell In R.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

        rCell.FormulaLocal = "=SEERRO(" & Mid(rCell.FormulaLocal, 2) & ",""-"")"

    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: You can also use `R.Select` but no need to use. So, I make it as comment.

Comment: While it's good to [remove `Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683), I fail to see how it could be the solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @GSerg Why not? I tested the codes. By removing `R.Select` I use `R.SpecialCells...` rather than `Selection.SpecialCells.....` Again my codes are tested.